# Segmentation fault in "end program" statement in Fortran

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

I have some Fortran code consisting of a subroutine and a call to it. It's supposed to calculate the mean of the elements in a matrix using a defined window size. For example, calling the subroutine on a (10,10) array using winsize=2 would return a (5,5) array.

The code is as shown:

```
SUBROUTINE avgwin(ts, sizelat,sizelon,winsize,size2,size3,ts_new)
implicit none
double precision, dimension(10,sizelat,sizelon) :: ts
double precision, dimension(winsize,winsize) :: store
double precision, dimension(10,size2,size3) :: ts_new
double precision :: par,ave
integer :: sizelat, sizelon,i,j,k,winsize,size2,size3
integer :: A, B,p,m,numb
A=0
B=0
par = 11 !Hypothetical value to be excluded
do i=1,10 !Looping through time
    do j=1,sizelat !Looping through latitude
        if ((j+winsize) > sizelat) then !Checks if it will exceed bounds
            exit !If it'll exceed, discard remaining cells
        end if
        do k=1,sizelon !Looping through longitude
            if ((k+winsize)>sizelon) then
               exit
            end if
            store = ts(i,j:j+winsize,k:k+winsize) !Gets the values for that window
            where (store == par) store = -99 !Replaces masked with -99
            ave = 0
            numb = 0 !Variable to count 
            do p=1,winsize
                do m=1,winsize
                    if (store(p,m)==-99) then !Evaluates if it's masked, i.e., =-99
                        ave = ave
                    else
                        ave = ave + store(p,m) !Sum of existent values
                        numb = numb +1 !Updates counting variable
                    end if
                end do
            end do
            ave = ave/numb !Calculates the mean
            ts_new(i,A,B) = ave 
            B=B+1
        end do
        B=0
        A=A+1
    end do
A=0
B=0
end do
END SUBROUTINE

program testefor
implicit none
double precision, dimension(10,10,10) :: teste
double precision, dimension(10,5,5) :: oi
integer :: i,j,k

do i=1,10
   do j=1,10
      do k=1,10
         teste(i,j,k)=i
      end do
   end do
 end do

CALL avgwin(teste,10,10,2,5,5,oi)
print*, oi(1,5,5)

end program testefor
```

When I'm running it, however, I get a Segmentation Fault. I tried debugging it with GDB and, to my surprise, it returns a correct result but segfaults when exiting the program. What I get from gdb can be found below:

```
Breakpoint 1, testefor () at testefor.f90:56
56      do i=1,10
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
   1.0000000000000000     

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400f73 in testefor () at testefor.f90:67
67  end program testefor
```

So the program is returning the correct (1,5,5) element = 1.0 but faulting somewhere else.

Can someone help me identify the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that can help is to compile the program in debug mode, and activate many debug switches.

In my case I compiled with `gfortran`, and I used:

1. `-g` to include debug symbols
2. `-fbacktrace` for a better stack trace
3. `-Wall` to enable all compiler warnings
4. `-fcheck=all` to enable run time checks (make the program slower, but are really useful during debugging).

These runtime checks found the error immediately:

```
At line 21 of file teste.F
Fortran runtime error: Array bound mismatch for dimension 1 of array 'store' (2/3)
```

The size of `store` is `(winsize, winsize)` but you copy an array into it of size `(windsize+1, winsize+1)`. If you slice an array in Fortran, it includes both the start and end index: `(1:10)` is from 1 to 10. If you have `(1:1+10)` it goes from 1 to 11, which means that its size is 11.

Without run time array bounds checks (in this case activated by `-fcheck=all`) this is really hard to debug and can cause all sorts of unexpected behaviour.

If you use a different compiler than `gfortran`, you need to read up on how to switch on such tests on your compiler, as the switches are not standardised.

Answer (score 2):

This is not meant as the answer to your question (I've already answered that), but a few hints that should help you.

1. If you loop over a multi-dimensional array, you should always have the inner-most loop over the first index, and so forth, so

   ```
   ! Inefficient way to do it:
   do i = 1, 10
       do j = 1, 10
           do k = 1, 10
               a(i, j, k) = i*j+k
           end do
       end do
   end do

   !Efficient way to do it:
   do k = 1, 10                   !  <-+
       do j = 1, 10               !    | swapped
           do i = 1, 10           !  <-+
               a(i, j, k) = i*j+k
           end do
       end do
   end do
   ```

   The way Fortran stores multi-dimensional arrays is with the first index changing fastest. The efficient method therefore reads successive elements, whereas the inefficient method needs to jump around in memory quite a bit.
2. Instead of this convoluted loop, you could just as easily use `SUM` and `COUNT`:

   - `COUNT` counts the instances of `.TRUE.` in an array, so your value of `numb` could just as easily be calculated as `numb=COUNT(store/=-99)`
   - `SUM` has the optional argument `MASK` that you can use to omit certain values. To sum up all the values that are not `-99`, you can use: `s = SUM(store, MASK=(store /= -99))`

   So you could replace about 15 lines of your code with just:

   ```
   ave = sum(store, MASK=(store/=par)) / count(store/=par)
   ```
3. Both `store` and `par` are `double precision`, and comparing floating point variables for absolute equality is [tricky](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/)